# Java access to MongoDb Lock/Unlock Concurrency

Tags: mongodb

I read some articles and they tell me MongoDb has Lock/Unlock Concurrency feature itself. So for example I have 2 Java instances access to one MongoDb to read & update data, each of them does the same thing:

```
1. Query all the qualified data from MongoDb  [read]
   (using DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query))
2. Do some calculation and update/write back to MongoDb (maybe all of them or 
   one of them) [write]
```

I want to make sure all the qualified data which query from the MongoDb should be "locked" because they might be updated/changed later; if the other Java instance accesses to the same data at the same time, it will return the wrong result. So all of them must be accessed by only one instance at the same time until the update/write process is done (Step 2).

How does MongoDb handle this situation above? Does it have some features to achieve it itself automatically or I have to do it manually (using other application such as zookeeper)?

Comment: You can't lock the results of one query from being modified by another process.  You could store those results in another table while they're "locked" and check these values before writing, but that still sounds like a recipe for race conditions.  Or you could consider using something like [Find and Modify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to set a flag on the "locked" records when you query them.

Answer (score 0):

Write operations are atomic on the level of a single document: no single write operation can atomically affect more than one document or more than one collection.

When a single write operation modifies multiple documents, the operation as a whole is not atomic, and other operations may interleave. The modification of a single document, or record, is always atomic, even if the write operation modifies multiple sub-documents within the single record.

No other operations are atomic; however, you can isolate a single write operation that affects multiple documents using the isolation operator.

[MongoDB has some buried documentation on isolating sequences of operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/)

In terms of the java driver, here is a simple example on how to implement atomic operations in Java

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB database = mongo.getDB("mydb");
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("testCollection");
// create a simple db object where counter value is 0
DBObject temp = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName").append("counter", 0);
// insert it into the collection
collection.insert(temp);
// create an increment query
DBObject modifier = new BasicDBObject("counter", 1);
DBObject incQuery = new BasicDBObject("$inc", modifier);
// create a search query
DBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject("name", "someName");
// increment a counter value atomically
WriteResult upRes = collection.update(searchQuery, incQuery);
```